# Выбор локализации при старте приложения

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Здравствуйте.
Есть такая проблема, нужно при старте приложения выбирать язык по нажатию на кнопку. Как это можно реализовать?
В данный момент язык выбирается с помощью `NSLocalizedString`. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В принципе вопрос [решается](http://habrahabr.ru/post/138263/), но это действительно костыль не согласующийся с адекватной работой в системе. Будьте непреклонны в отговаривании, ссылайтесь на HIG iOS или на ответы в этом посте

Comment: Спасибо, буду иметь в ввиду.

Comment: опередили со сылкой) но да, не нужно так делать, зачем юзерам лишнее движение с выбором дабавлять если ось сама все делает и так

Answer (score 3):

Нужно писать свой (или искать готовый) механизм локализации.

Честно говоря никогда не понимал такого подхода и всячески старался отговорить клиентов от этой "фичи", т.к. расходы на ее реализацию большие, а польза - минимальная.

Ды и выглядит как какой-то windows-way...

Comment: Я вот тоже все пытаюсь отговорить но пока безрезультатно)))
Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Сам сталкивался с такой проблемой, лично я решил эту проблему с помощью создания еще двух ViewController а дальше просто сделать так,что бы по нажатию кнопки языка,открывала этот ViewController.